# Multiple Charts with Chart Module?

Tags: 7, charts

I need to present multiple graphs in a single page. Is it possible to do this using the Charts module? Up until now I have been using the following to return a chart to the page.

```
return theme('chart', array(
                      'chart' => $chart,
                    ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while doing the following worked, I do not know why it did not work from the beginning :

```
return theme('chart', array(
              'chart' => $chart,
              )).theme('chart', array(
              'chart' => $chart,
              ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the [chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, not the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module ... please add a link in your question to the module you're using.

It'd be interesting to know what result you get by only replacing `theme` by `echo` ... similar to what is shown in the [D7 examples using theme()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2434061#d7theme) (using the chart-without-s module).

If that doesn't help then consider including the related coding for building the chart array in your question.